# event.preventDefault does not work for CMD+R refresh

Tags: javascript, events

I was trying to intercept and prevent all default events.  Can anyone point to the documentation / source of truth to show that this is not possible for e.g.: `cmd`+`r` (Mac) (or `ctrl` + `r` for windows).

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="debug">
            Debug:
        </div>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
                const otherKeys = []
                if (event.ctrlKey) {
                    otherKeys.push("CTRL")
                }
                if (event.shiftKey) {
                    otherKeys.push("SHIFT")
                }
                if (event.altKey) {
                    otherKeys.push("ALT")
                }
                if (event.metaKey) {
                    otherKeys.push("META")
                }

                let otherKeysStr = otherKeys.join(",")
                if (otherKeysStr.length) {
                    otherKeysStr = `(${otherKeysStr})`
                }

                document.getElementById("debug").innerText += (` ${event.key} ${otherKeysStr}`)

                event.stopImmediatePropagation()
                event.stopPropagation()
                event.preventDefault()
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could check the unload event (triggered when exiting the page )

Comment: You can not block certain events to keep the user from leaving....

Comment: It makes sense @epascarello it would just be nice to see the documentation for that.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13891#c50 keypress is the wrong thing to use, keydown should be the correct event

Answer (score 0):

As lois6b suggested, you can at least give the user the option of not refreshing the page using:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
    return '';
})
```